# Why does this C code always output a smiley face?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//A simple program that asks for the user's name and prints it back out.
int main()
{
    char name[15]; 
    printf("What is your name? ");
    scanf("%c",&name);
    printf("Name: %c",name);
}
```

Not matter what the input is, a smiley face is always the output. I realize that if I change the %c to a %s, the program would run just fine but what I'm wondering is why, out of all things, a smiley face is the output. 
Also, if the second %c is replaced with a %s i.e.

```
char name[15]; 
printf("What is your name? ");
scanf("%c",&name);
printf("Name: %s",name);
```

then an @ symbol is printed after the 1st character of the input. For example, if the input is "Sam", then the output would be "S@". Any ideas as to why this happens?

Comment: It doesn't always output that. I don't think it does.

Comment: Probably because the low-order byte of the memory address of "name" happens to be the character value for a smiley face on your system. Purely coincidental.

Comment: Always, *always* check the return of any of the `scanf` family of functions, especially when taking user input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's undefined behavior, try

```
scanf("%14s", name);
```

You pass the wrong parameter to the "%c" specifier which expects a pointer to a single `char`. Instead you need the `"%s"` specifier and since `name` is an array it's automatically a pointer to it's first element so you don't need the `&` address of operator.

Comment: you were used wrong format specifier that's you didn't get output. use %s instead of %c. Because %c takes only one character and %s takes input as a string. there is also do not use of &. because of array name represent as a base address.